# Maping S3ObjectInputStream into input stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with AWS Java api.

Retrieving file returns `S3Object` that contains `S3ObjectInputStream` which i read data from.

However, i would like to map `S3ObjectInputStream` into normal `InputStream`, is something like that possible?

I would love to create API that hides this implementation.

I know if i have small file i can just store bytes in array and create `InputStream` from that, but big files will be needed too.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html). It seems that this is a sub-class of `InputStream`, so all you have to do is casting.

Answer (score 1):

For S3 Java 1, refer to this example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/GetObject.java

If you are using V2, see this client method. You can get a byte[] and then use that to meet your requirements:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#getObjectAsBytes-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-